# Uploading Image File using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I'm trying to manually post image using JQuery to a remote server.
the file is something like "c:\temp\1.jpg" and the post is in the background.

i tried using something i saw online but doesnt work:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("file", "c:\\temp\\1.jpg");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:61602/home/FileUpload",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success: " + result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was error uploading files!");
    }
});
```

The idea is to upload from a mobile device where the html File is unavailable, but i gave the user ability to select file location to upload..

Thanks in advance,
Amit

Comment: You cannot access the file system from javascript.

Comment: jgroenen, what about if the webpage is running in android with webview which i gave filesystem privilage ?

Comment: Then checkout phonegap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Answer (score 0):

You have to send upload control data in FormData like this

```
var form_data = new FormData();
var objFiles = $("input#fUpload").prop("files");
form_data.append("file", objFiles[position]);
```

If there is one fileupload control in your form, postion value is 0

```
postion = 0
```

---

```
private void handlepostImage()
     {
         string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
         {
             HttpPostedFile objHttpPostedFile = (HttpPostedFile)Request.Files[i];
             string filename = Server.MapPath("../Uploads/Contents/" + guid + Path.GetExtension(objHttpPostedFile.FileName));
             objHttpPostedFile.SaveAs(filename);
         }
Response.Write("{\"fileGuid\":\"" + guid + "\"}");
}
```

You can return file name to your clientside